# Insert datagrid values to Database

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, loops, datagridview

I am trying to insert one by one raw data in a data grid to a SQL database.
on this code looping and inserting the first row only(The first row is duplicating as `DataGrid` raw count). I need to insert all rows one by one via a loop. How do I fix it?

```
for (int i = 0; i < DGWRelations.Rows.Count; i++)
{
     int _PID = Convert.ToInt32(
          DGWRelations.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString());
     int _RELATION = Convert.ToInt32(
          DGWRelations.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString());
     string _NAME = DGWRelations.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
     int _MOBILE = Convert.ToInt32(
          DGWRelations.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value.ToString());
     string _NIC = DGWRelations.CurrentRow.Cells[4].Value.ToString();
     string _JOB = DGWRelations.CurrentRow.Cells[5].Value.ToString();
     string _OTHER = DGWRelations.CurrentRow.Cells[6].Value.ToString();
     cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [dbo].[DATATBLE] ([PID] ,[Relationship] ,[Name] ,[ContactNo] ,[NIC] ,[Job] ,[OtherDetails]) VALUES (@PID,@Relationship,@Name,@ContactNo,@NIC,@Job,@OtherDetails)", con);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PID", _PID);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Relationship", _RELATION);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", _NAME);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContactNo", _MOBILE);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NIC", _NIC);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Job", _JOB);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OtherDetails", _OTHER);
     int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: There almost certainly no reason to dig the values out of the control and manually fashion SQL in a loop.  The DB Provider objects can add, update and delete any number of row changes with one line of code.  Consult the documentation and/or a quality tutorial for details.

Comment: Related - don't use [addwithvalue](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to insert your `CurrentRow` for each iteration of loop.

Therefore if you iterate like this:

```
int _PID = Convert.ToInt32(DGWRelations.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString());
```

You can edit rest of your codeblocks same way and try if that works.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make it

```
DGWRelations.Rows[i].Cells[0]
```

Also, why are you inserting by looping it all the time. Use a Stored Procedure and User Defined Table Types for it.